# Regex MatchCollection from merge fields in string

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

I have a large string with the content from a document. It contain a number of merge fields, and I would like to fetch them in order to generate the value for the merge fields.

The string could be like this:

```
string text = "This is a test with merge fields. [First_field], [Second_field] and [Third_field]. Not to forget the [Forth_field]."
```

The list I would like to get out of this, would be like this:

- [First_field]
- [Second_field]
- [Third_field]
- [Forth_field]

I know it can be done in Regex, but this is definitely not my strength. I have tried with the following code, but it seems to create a single result (from the first and last brackets):

```
Regex.Matches(text, @"\[.*\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are matching every character between `[` and `]`. That **includes** `]`, meaning you swallow every field. What you need is called **lazy** matching that can be done using a `?` after the quantifier:

```
@"\[.*?\]"
```

Alternatively, you could just match any character **except** `]`, which is done using the negation of a character class `[^]`

```
@"\[[^\]]*\]"
```